# Rock, Paper, Scissor Project (Odin Project) - Button Assitance

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have been trying for hours now to make it so that when you click on any of the buttons (rock, paper, scissors) on the page, it would pass on the value of either rock, paper, or scissors, to my variable "userChoice". I am still very new to javascript so bear in mind that my code could be very wrong. Any help/suggestions would be incredibly appreciated!

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
  <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<h1>Welcome to the Rock, Paper, Scissors Championship!</h1>
<body>

  <div class="selections">
    <div class="rock">
      <input type="image" id="rock" src="/home/johannesvw3/Desktop/web-projects/Rock/images/rock.png">
      <button class="text-rock">ROCK</button>
      <div class="paper">
        <input type="image" id="paper" src="/home/johannesvw3/Desktop/web-projects/Rock/images/paper.png">
        <button class="text-paper">PAPER</button>
        <div class="scissor">
          <input type="image" id="scissors" src="/home/johannesvw3/Desktop/web-projects/Rock/images/scissors.png">
          <button class="text-scissors">SCISSORS</button>
    </div>  
    <div class="scoreboard">Scoreboard
      <div class="user">User:
      <div class="comp">Computer:
    </div>


  <script src="rock.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**and here is my Javascript:**

```
//userChoice
const myButtonRock = document.querySelector('.text-rock');
const myButtonPaper = document.querySelector('.text-paper');
const myButtonScissors = document.querySelector('.text-scissors');

function userChoices() {
  let userChoice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  return userChoice;
}
  myButtonRock.onclick = function() {
    userChoice('rock');
  }

  myButtonPaper.onclick = function() {
    userChoice('paper');
  }

  myButtonScissors.onclick = function() {
    userChoice('scissors');
  }

  //Computer Choice
  function compChoice() {
    let compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    if (compChoice == 0) {
      compChoice = "rock";
    } else if (compChoice == 1) {
      compChoice = "paper";
    } else {
      compChoice = "scissors";
    }
    return compChoice
  }

  let userScore = 0;
  let compScore = 0;
  let draws = 0;

  
  function playRound(userChoice, compChoice) {
  
  //Result Messages
    let userWinsRound = "You Win!"
    let compWinsRound = "You Lose :(";
    let draw = "It's a draw";
  
    //Rock Choice
    if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "scissors") {
      alert("user score:" + " " + ++userScore + " " + userWinsRound)
    } else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "paper") {
      alert("computer score:" + " " + ++compScore + " " + compWinsRound)
    } else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "rock") {
      alert("draws:" + " " + ++draws + " " + draw)
    }
    //paper Choice
    if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "rock") {
      alert("user score:" + " " + ++userScore + " " + userWinsRound)
    } else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "scissors") {
      alert("computer score:" + " " + ++compScore + " " + compWinsRound)
    } else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "paper") {
      alert("draws:" + " " + ++draws + " " + draw)
    }
    //scissors Choice
    if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "paper") {
      alert("user score:" + " " + ++userScore + " " + userWinsRound)
    } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "rock") {
      alert("computer score:" + " " + ++compScore + " " + compWinsRound)
    } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "scissors") {
      alert("draws:" + " " + ++draws + " " + compWinsRound)
    } else {
      return "Something Went Wrong";
    }
        
    }
    
      while (userScore < 5 && compScore < 5) {
        console.log(playRound(userChoices(), compChoice()));
      }
```

Comment: I notice, among other things, that you're passing a string into this function `userChoice('paper');`, but that function doesn't exist. You should put your code into a sample program, perhaps in JSFiddle, and then share that.

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing that out! I have made some edits to the code. The problem now seems to be that it does not wait for the buttons to be clicked. The game just runs automatically. Here is the JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/u8cwja5r/1/